# Swift: iPhone's volume is low when trying to change speech to iPhone's voice in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avspeechsynthesizer, sfspeechrecognizer

I am trying Speech recognition sample. If I started to recognise my speech via microphone, then I tried to get iPhone's voice of that recognised text. It is working. But, voice is too low. Can u guide me on this?

Rather than, if I am trying in simple button action, with `AVSpeechUtterance` code, volume is normal.

After that, If I go for `startRecognise()` method, volume is too low.

**My Code**

```
func startRecognise()
{
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()  //2
    do
    {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeDefault)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
    }
    recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
    guard let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode else {
        fatalError("Audio engine has no input node")
    }
    guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else {
        fatalError("Unable to create an SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object")
    }
    recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true
    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
        if result != nil
        {
            let lastword = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString.components(separatedBy: " ").last
            if lastword == "repeat" || lastword == "Repeat"{
                self.myUtterance2 = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "You have spoken repeat")
                self.myUtterance2.rate = 0.4
                self.myUtterance2.volume = 1.0
                self.myUtterance2.pitchMultiplier = 1.0
                self.synth1.speak(self.myUtterance2)
                // HERE VOICE IS TOO LOW. 
            }
        }
    })
    let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)  //11
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, when) in
    self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
    }
    audioEngine.prepare()
    do 
    {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } 
    catch 
    {
        print("audioEngine couldn't start because of an error.")
    }
}
```

**My Button Action**

```
func buttonAction()
{
   self.myUtterance2 = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "You are in button action")
   self.myUtterance2.rate = 0.4
   self.myUtterance2.volume = 1.0
   self.myUtterance2.pitchMultiplier = 1.0
   self.synth1.speak(self.myUtterance2)
   // Before going for startRecognise() method, 
   //I tried with buttonAction(), 
   //this time volume is normal. 
   //After startRecognise() method call, volume is too low in both methods.
}
```

Comment: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker -- add this

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Finally, I got Solution.

```
func startRecognise()
{
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()  //2
    do
    {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeDefault)
        //try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
    }

    ... 
}
```

Once I comment this line, `try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)`, volume is working normal.

Answer (score 4):

After digging into the technical details its observed that, `overrideOutputAudioPort()` temporarily changes the current audio route.

```
func overrideOutputAudioPort(_ portOverride: AVAudioSession.PortOverride) throws
```

If your app uses the `playAndRecord` category, calling this method with the AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker option causes audio to be routed to the `built-in speaker` and `microphone` regardless of other settings.

This change remains in effect only until the current route changes or you call this method again with the AVAudioSession.PortOverride.none option.

```
try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeDefault)
```

If you would prefer to `permanently enable` this behavior, you should instead set the category's `defaultToSpeaker` option. Setting this option will always route to the speaker rather than receiver if no other accessory such as headphones are in use.

In **Swift 5.x** above code looks like -

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
  try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord)
  try audioSession.setMode(.default)
  try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
  try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
} catch {
  debugPrint("Enable to start audio engine")
  return
}
```

By setting mode to the `measurement`, its responsible for minimize the amount of `system-supplied signal` processing to input and output signals.

```
try audioSession.setMode(.measurement)
```

By commenting this mode and using `default` mode responsible for `permanently enabling` the audio route to the `built-in speaker` and `microphone`.

Thanks @McDonal_11 for you answer. Hope this will helps to understand the technical details.

Comment: Thanks for ur details. I didn't aware of this one. :)